# Apply web.config style xdt transform to other XML files in project

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, web-config, transform, xdt-transform

We have an XML configuration file in our project that needs to be altered for publishing. We have been using web.config transforms very successfully. Is it possible to apply such transformations to other XML files in our project/solution when publishing for different build targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [app.config transform Visual Studio Add in](http://sedodream.com/2011/08/17/AppconfigTransformVisualStudioAddIn.aspx) does exactly what I want.